# Generating Ctrl + F1 key combination from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This was asked quite a few times here, but I can't manage to get it working (possibly due to the AddOn; see below). 
I am a beginner in javascript - so this is the most obvious explanation.. :)

So the goal is to send a **Ctrl + F1** key combination (from inside the browser - using javascript or something else; using an OS level tool - like AutoHotKey - is doable but not applicable in my case). 
The Ctrl + F1 key combination will be received & handled by a (3rd party) Firefox AddOn. Does the generated key combination (see the sample code I use below) reach the 3rd party Firefox AddOn (which correctly handles this key combination when performed manually)?
My target browser is Firefox, OSs are Windows & Linux ideally.

```
<script>
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 112;       // # F1 code value
  e.ctrlkey = true;     // control key pressed
  $(document).trigger(e);// trigger event on document
</script>
```

Thanks & cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Keyboard events created by Javascript can only trigger event handlers within that page; they cannot trigger keyboard shortcuts in the browser or operating system.

Comment: Thanks, that means I will have to pursue the remaining option: an OS level tool :)

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/ is a very popular tool if you're under windows.

Answer (score 0):

[RobotJs](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs): [Wiki](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/wiki)

```
var robot = require("robotjs");

robot.keyTap("f1", "control");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the keys to your operation system, you may use node-key-sender.

Install it with `npm install --save-dev node-key-sender`.

And send a text to the keyboard using:

```
var ks = require('node-key-sender');
ks.sendKeys(['control', 'f1']);
```

Check the documentation page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-key-sender.